# to deep copy byte[] use clone() or not?

Tags: java, clone

I want to copy a byte[] to not return the initial object, but a deep copy. I'm aware of the fact that using clone() is not recommended, but as i look it up on google&co I mostly see clone() for a copy with byte[].

Is it just laziness of people or is it a valid method to copy an array of bytes?

Comment: that's the question, is clone valid on byte array, because byte is a primitve type and so the clone method will give a deep copy?

Comment: Byte is primitive, but array is not. Array is the object.

Comment: Why is clone not recommended ? You don't even need deep copy: byte is not a complex type so you can't go any deeper.

Comment: My goal is to copy a byte array so my method returns a clean copy which can't manipulate the origin.